# Why same code return list and tuple pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
if calculation_type == 'week':
    df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key=order_date_field, freq='W-SUN')])[
        display_fields].sum().reset_index().sort_values(order_date_field)
    df[order_date_field] = df[order_date_field].apply(lambda x: x.date().isoformat())
else:
    df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key=order_date_field, freq='M')])[
        display_fields].sum().reset_index().sort_values(order_date_field)
    df[order_date_field] = df[order_date_field].apply(lambda x: calendar.month_name[x.date().month])
return df.to_dict('records')
```

[image]

Question is next why if == week , return list and else return tuple?

df where 4 elems = list
df where 2 elems = tutple

Comment: Please provide a sample of your dataframe.

Comment: added df to question @richardec

Answer (score 0):

It was mine fault when i call the function i put accidentally coma after the function
for e.i `year = get_calculation(args),`
and weeks `week = get_calculation(args)`